# How do I prevent "wobbling" of digital clock?

Tags: javascript, html, css, datetime, real-time-clock

For my digital signage project I made a simple digital clock with date in JS. But when I align the clock on the right side of the top bar (which I need to do), the text shifts back and forth when the seconds update. This is due to the condensed font I am using (and I have to use it). Any ideas how to prevent that from happening?

Here's my code:

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    var o = today.getMonth();
    var a = today.getDate();
    var d = today.getDay();

    var monthnames = new Array();
    monthnames[0] = "January";
    monthnames[1] = "February";
    monthnames[2] = "March";
    monthnames[3] = "April";
    monthnames[4] = "May";
    monthnames[5] = "June";
    monthnames[6] = "July";
    monthnames[7] = "August";
    monthnames[8] = "September";
    monthnames[9] = "Oktober";
    monthnames[10] = "November";
    monthnames[11] = "December";

    var weekdays = new Array();
    weekdays[0] = "Sunday";
    weekdays[1] = "Monday";
    weekdays[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekdays[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekdays[4] = "Thursday";
    weekdays[5] = "Friday";
    weekdays[6] = "Saturday";

    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    a = checkTime(a);


    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML =
        `<h1>${weekdays[d]}, ${a} ${monthnames[o]}, ${y}, <span id="clocktime">${h}:${m}:${s}</h1>`;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // Fügt vor einstelligen Zahlen (i > 10) eine Null hinzu
    return i;
}

startTime()
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans');
* {
  font-family: Ropa Sans;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.time {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="time" id="clock"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a variable-width font and right-align and not have the text move around. One of those two things (variable-width or right-alignment) has to give way (well, probably; you might just minimize one). :-)

You've said you have to use the variable-width font, so I have two workarounds (I think calling them "solutions" would be overkill :-) ):

1. Put the time at the beginning. This minimizes the effect; it only happens when the day changes.
2. Put the text left-aligned in a container that's at the maximum size you'll need, with the container right-aligned.
3. Make just the clock digits fixed-width and see if anyone complains. :-)

I didn't think of the third one until late, but #3 is probably your best bet.

Here's an example of #1:

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    var o = today.getMonth();
    var a = today.getDate();
    var d = today.getDay();

    var monthnames = new Array();
    monthnames[0] = "January";
    monthnames[1] = "February";
    monthnames[2] = "March";
    monthnames[3] = "April";
    monthnames[4] = "May";
    monthnames[5] = "June";
    monthnames[6] = "July";
    monthnames[7] = "August";
    monthnames[8] = "September";
    monthnames[9] = "Oktober";
    monthnames[10] = "November";
    monthnames[11] = "December";

    var weekdays = new Array();
    weekdays[0] = "Sunday";
    weekdays[1] = "Monday";
    weekdays[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekdays[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekdays[4] = "Thursday";
    weekdays[5] = "Friday";
    weekdays[6] = "Saturday";

    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    a = checkTime(a);


    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML =
        `<h1><span id="clocktime">${h}:${m}:${s}</span> - ${weekdays[d]}, ${a} ${monthnames[o]}, ${y}</h1>`;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // Fügt vor einstelligen Zahlen (i > 10) eine Null hinzu
    return i;
}

startTime()
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans');
* {
  font-family: Ropa Sans;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.time {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="time" id="clock"></div>
</div>
```

Here's #2, using a temporary-and-probably-rubbish value for the width; you'll want to do more diligence on the width to use:

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    var o = today.getMonth();
    var a = today.getDate();
    var d = today.getDay();

    var monthnames = new Array();
    monthnames[0] = "January";
    monthnames[1] = "February";
    monthnames[2] = "March";
    monthnames[3] = "April";
    monthnames[4] = "May";
    monthnames[5] = "June";
    monthnames[6] = "July";
    monthnames[7] = "August";
    monthnames[8] = "September";
    monthnames[9] = "Oktober";
    monthnames[10] = "November";
    monthnames[11] = "December";

    var weekdays = new Array();
    weekdays[0] = "Sunday";
    weekdays[1] = "Monday";
    weekdays[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekdays[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekdays[4] = "Thursday";
    weekdays[5] = "Friday";
    weekdays[6] = "Saturday";

    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    a = checkTime(a);


    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML =
        `<h1>${weekdays[d]}, ${a} ${monthnames[o]}, ${y}, <span id="clocktime">${h}:${m}:${s}</span></h1>`;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // Fügt vor einstelligen Zahlen (i > 10) eine Null hinzu
    return i;
}

startTime()
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans');
* {
  font-family: Ropa Sans;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.time {
  width: 450px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="time" id="clock"></div>
</div>
```

Here's #3. This time, the width isn't completely arbitrary, it's `1ch`, which is the width of the `0` in the current font ([details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)):

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    var o = today.getMonth();
    var a = today.getDate();
    var d = today.getDay();

    var monthnames = new Array();
    monthnames[0] = "January";
    monthnames[1] = "February";
    monthnames[2] = "March";
    monthnames[3] = "April";
    monthnames[4] = "May";
    monthnames[5] = "June";
    monthnames[6] = "July";
    monthnames[7] = "August";
    monthnames[8] = "September";
    monthnames[9] = "Oktober";
    monthnames[10] = "November";
    monthnames[11] = "December";

    var weekdays = new Array();
    weekdays[0] = "Sunday";
    weekdays[1] = "Monday";
    weekdays[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekdays[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekdays[4] = "Thursday";
    weekdays[5] = "Friday";
    weekdays[6] = "Saturday";

    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    a = checkTime(a);


    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML =
        `<h1>${weekdays[d]}, ${a} ${monthnames[o]}, ${y}, <span id="clocktime">${clockDigits(h)}${clockDigits(":")}${clockDigits(m)}${clockDigits(":")}${clockDigits(s)}</span></h1>`;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        return "0" + i;  // Fügt vor einstelligen Zahlen (i > 10) eine Null hinzu
    }
    return String(i);
}

function clockDigits(s) {
    return String(s).split("").map(ch => `<span class="digit">${ch}</span>`).join("");
}

startTime()
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans');
* {
  font-family: Ropa Sans;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.time {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
#clocktime .digit {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1ch;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>x</div>
<div>x</div>
<div>x</div>
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="time" id="clock"></div>
</div>
```

(Note that in that third one I also made `checkTime` reliably return a string instead of sometimes returning a string and other times return a number.)

Comment: #3 seems like a good option. Be aware that zero is typically the widest number character in a font so use that for your width.

Comment: @BryceHowitson - FWIW, I just learned about `ch` units, which are perfect for solution #3 above. Updated. :-)

Comment: Yes! Not a unit I need very often but it is perfect in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If the font spacing itself is allowed to be set to a fixed with (at least for the numbers), you can wrap each digit in a span:

*Note: jQuery is just to make an smaller example:*

```js
setInterval(function(){
  $('span').each(function(){
    const newDigit = parseInt(this.innerHTML) +1
    this.innerHTML = newDigit > 9 ? 0 : newDigit;
  })
},1000);
```

```css
span{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 8.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>1</span><span>2</span>:<span>3</span><span>4</span>
```